# Using a global array of pointer to cleanup before exiting in C

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a small program that contains a variable that I need to malloc:

```
char **v;
v = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_EVENTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_EVENTS; i++)
        v[i] = (char *)malloc(MAX_NAME_SIZE);
```

In order to make **Valgrind** happy, to avoid any memory leaks, I set up handlers for termination signals. This handler will simply free that allocation before exiting, as well as terminating child processes.

```
 static void term_handler() {
    if (v != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_EVENTS; i++) {
            if (v[i] != NULL)
                free(v[i]);
        }
        free(v);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PROCS; i++)
        if (children[i])
            kill(children[i], SIGTERM);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

To access `v` from the handler, I put it as a global variable. `children` is a static array `pid_t children[MAX_PROCS];` but could potentially be *malloced* as well.

What is the cleanest way to access those allocations from the handler? Having global variables is not recommend but nor are memory leaks and not properly terminated programs.
Should I keep an array of pointers to my allocations as a global variable? Or should I just avoid handling unexpected signals?

Comment: Calling `free` from a signal handler is a terrible idea. What if a signal arrives while your program is in the middle of another `malloc` / `free`?

Comment: You don't need to free all allocated memory; it's automatically freed when the program exits.

Comment: @melpomene I am using sigaction to mask incoming signals while freeing.

Comment: @Shawn isn't it better practice to handle that directly from the program instead of delegating to the kernel?

Comment: the posted code will fail, with a seg fault exception unless all of the entries in the array `v[` are set to some valid heap pointer.  Better/easier to have the allocation of `v] be via `calloc()` then the code can just loop through the whole array of `v` with out consideration, because the function: `free()` properly handles being passed a NULL pointer

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120105-00/?p=8683/

Comment: @melpomene note that this question is tagged for Linux

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Sure, but the general principle still applies.

Comment: Not in this case -- here the questioner wants to use valgrind to check for memory leaks, which is difficult to do if the process doesn't try to explicitly free all its memory buffers  before exiting (because valgrind can't know which still-allocated memory was intentionally not freed, vs which represents a genuine leak due to a programming error)

Comment: @Arkon - no. Especially not when it leads people to trying to do strange convoluted stuff like you're trying. Worry about actual memory leaks, not harmless stuff still reachable when the program exits.

Comment: @Shawn,  It is a very poor programming practice to leave trash around that the OS has to cleanup and will not work when writing an embedded application that will be running for an extended period (say years)

Comment: @user3629249 sure it is. You don't normally manually close standard input etc. before a process ends, do you? Same idea. Let the OS clean things up. Embedded is a whole different story, of course, but I really doubt OP is working in that kind of environment - probably wouldn't be doing any allocation for example.

Comment: @Shawn you don't close standard input because you didn't open standard input -- the OS opened it for you.  Things that your code *did* allocate, OTOH, are best closed by your code as well, if only so that inadvertent resource leaks can be more easily detected and fixed, rather than being hidden amongst the deliberate ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Signal handlers are tricky, in that they are called asynchronously, and therefore there are only a [small set of function calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) that are safe to call from within a signal handler.  In particular, allocating or freeing memory from within a signal-handler is a no-no (as is calling [exit()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)!), so don't do it.

If you want to make sure the memory gets freed(*), however, you can do so by having your signal handler "tell" your program's main thread that it is time for it to exit.  The main thread can then break out of its event loop, free the memory, and do any other cleanup work it would normally do before exiting.

So then the question becomes, how can a signal handler safely tell the main thread to perform a controlled/graceful exit?

If the main thread is running an event loop that executes on a fixed schedule (e.g. every so-many milliseconds), it may be as easy as declaring a global variable (e.g. `volatile bool pleaseQuitNow = false;` that the main thread tests on each iteration of its event loop, and having the signal-handler set that variable to a different value.  The main thread will then see the changed variable on its next iteration and respond by breaking out of the event loop.

If the main thread's event-loop is event-based, on the other hand (e.g. it is blocked inside [select()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) or [poll()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or similar and the call won't return for some indefinite amount of time), then an alternate way to wake up the main thread would be to create a [pipe()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) or  [socketpair()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) at program startup, and have the main thread watch one of the two file-descriptors for read-ready status.  Then when the signal handler runs, it can send() a byte on the other file descriptor, which will cause the first file descriptor to indicate ready-for-read status.  The main thread can respond to that ready-for-read status by breaking out of its event loop and exiting gracefully.

In addition to avoiding async-signal-unsafe calls, the benefit of doing it this way is that you have only one shutdown/cleanup-path to test/debug/maintain, instead of two.

(*) Of course on any modern OS the memory will get freed anyway, by the OS's process-cleanup routines; but valgrind will complain about memory leaks, so it's better to free the memory manually if possible, if only so that you can use valgrind to find "real" memory leaks without having to sort through a bunch of false-positives every time.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very insightful! My main loop is looking at inotify events, so waiting to read on a file descriptor. I am going to look at select/poll and epoll to read from multiple fd and process accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I don't need signal handling if using poll with a single fd after all: poll will be raising a `EINTR: Interrupted system call` that I can catch and process with clean up?

Comment: ^ and use `signalfd` with `poll` ?

Comment: If by "wait" you mean "blocking in a call to `wait()`", I haven't found a really elegant solution to that; the best I could come up with was to call `waitpid(theChildPID, &status, WNOHANG)` in a loop instead (along with a call to sleep()/snooze() to avoid spinning the CPU), so that I could periodically check the signal-fd as well.  Ideally your code would never block anywhere except in `select()` or `poll()` or some other function that knows to return when a byte has been received on the socket.

Comment: (of course if your main thread is blocked in a call to `wait()` you may not actually *want* to exit until the child process has terminated, if it is more important to guarantee that the child process has been shut down cleanly than to have the parent process exit quickly.  Hopefully your child processes are well-behaved enough that you don't have to make that decision)